# align-items in 'row' do not work when i use a custom class in container-fluid in bootstarp 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I just started learning front end development and after studying basics of html5/css3, moved on to bootstrap 4. Now, O have been trying to make a copy of facebook login page, and used `container-fluid` for 100% width and then used `container` and `row` and `column` inside it. To match the background color, i added a custom class to `container-fluid` and then to align items vertically, i used `align-items-end` in `row`. But, for some reason, it does not work; I had been looking into it but couldn't find anything. Then, I tried something which let it happen. below is the code of both the cases, kindly help me understand what is going on and why it didn't work before and now why is it working? Help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<head>

    <!-- Charset -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Responsive -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- styelsheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
        .bg-fakebook {
            background-color: #3b5999 !important;
            min-height: 82px;
        }

        .fakebook-weight {
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Title -->
    <title>fakebook</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-fakebook">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-end">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3 class="fakebook-weight">fakebook</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------
         JS files: jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS
    --------------------------------------------------------------- -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"          integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>               <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"             integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"            integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q05bi.jpg)

---

Then, after trying many things, i added `bg-fakebook` to `row` as well which worked.

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-fakebook">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-end bg-fakebook">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3 class="fakebook-weight">fakebook</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17rhU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to align middle first you have to `display: flex` the parent. Than add the alignment `top center or bottom`. like this

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-fakebook d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-end">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3 class="fakebook-weight">fakebook</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To learn bootstrap 4 you must learn **flex**  first. BTW Happy Learning.